# Is there a one line text input box in python 2.7?

Tags: python-2.7, user-interface, text, input, tkinter

Java has a method that opens a text box and pulls the answer:

```
JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, "What's your name?");
```

Is there a similar easy solution for pulling input text?
Edit: I understand that packages exist and what they are, I'm asking if you know of a package that has a *one line* solution

Comment: That's not "Java", that's a specific front-end toolkit in Java. Python has front-end toolkits too; which one are you using?

Comment: python 2.7. I don't care what method it takes to get their, I just want the text box, so whatever you think is best

Comment: Are you asking about the `Entry` widget, or are you asking about how to get a popup dialog that includes an `Entry` widget?

Answer (score 1):

In python if you are using Tkinter then you can use

```
Entry()
```

Check [this link](http://www.python-course.eu/tkinter_entry_widgets.php) out for more clear guidelines

Comment: But how do I use that inside of another program that is tkinter based?

Answer (score 1):

Vanilla python has no methods for UI interfaces (I believe as any other programming language - Java, C#, C++, %any_other_language% use separate libraries or frameworks to create UI). There is number of libraries for python which are used to draw different user interfaces and which would allow you to do this. You could check this list, pick up the one you like more and read how you could do it there:

https://wiki.python.org/moin/GuiProgramming

On the other hand, the most commonly used one is tkinter. For tkinter, you could check examples here (there is example of creating whole python program - a loan calculator - with a UI)

http://www.python-course.eu/tkinter_entry_widgets.php

Comment: I looked into that a lot before asking this question, but I could not figure it out. Could you provide an example? The program is running a pygame window

Comment: @doominabox1 the stackoverflow is for specific programming questions - which means you need to show us what you have tried and which specific issue you encountered. I.e. 'here is my code, I try to add this to show the textbox but I get that error'.